# Plugin Development "ignore close event"

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, plugins

I'm quite new in either QGis-Plugin- and Qt-development.

I started to work on a Plugin, which displays a dialog (I used pluginBuilder and Qt-Designer) in which the user should select some options.
After the user has clicked Ok the action is performed. Everything works well so far.
Now I'd like to check the options, and if important information is missig I display a QMessageBox which tells the user what was wrong. So now to my Question: In this case the plugin-Dialog should not be closed but stay open for the user to fix the issue.
Can anybody give an example how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this, you'll have to change the default code, both in the `.ui` and in the main python file. Basically, you have to use [signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) to catch the `click` event on your OK button.

First thing first: in your `XX_dialog_base.ui` file, replace the `QDialogButtonBox` object (which contains the "OK" and "Cancel" buttons) with 2 simple `QPushButton` objects. Let's say that the "OK" Push Button is called `runButton` (in QT Designer, you can set the name of an object in the right panel).

Then, the main work: in your main `.py` file, you have to import `pyqtSignal` and `pyqtSlot` (`from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot`). To display a message box, you also have to import `QMessageBox` (`from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox`).

Your `run` method should simply look like this:

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""

    # add some code to preset the GUI if needed
    self.dlg.runButton.setEnabled(True)

    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show() 

    # Run the dialog event loop
    self.dlg.exec_()
```

At the beginning of the `__init__` method, add the following line: `super(XXX, self).__init__()` (don't ask me why, it just won't work otherwise). Replace `XXX` with the name of your class (which is usually the name of your plugin).

In the `initGui` method, add (wherever) the following line: `self.dlg.runButton.clicked.connect( self.onStart )`. This will connect the "clicked on runButton" event to the `onStart` method, which will look like this (you can write it wherever you want):

```
@pyqtSlot()
def onStart(self):
    # here you can do whatever you want before running the main code

    # for example, display a message under some condition:
    if wrongOptions:
        messageBox = QMessageBox()
        messageBox.setWindowTitle( "Title" )
        messageBox.setText( "Content" )
        messageBox.setIcon( QMessageBox.Critical )
        messageBox.exec_()
        return

    else:
        self.dlg.runButton.setEnabled(False) # Disable OK button
        self.dlg.closeButton.setEnabled(False) # Disable cancel button
        self.main() # Run main function
```

You may need to add some changes to what I wrote, but this should cover most of what you want. Note that with this approach (events and signals), you can event control the options *before* the user clicks on OK (no need for warning messages).

Bonus links:

- [Some help on message boxes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qmessagebox.htm)
- [The main python file](https://github.com/ArMoraer/QGISStrahler/blob/master/strahler.py) of a plugin I wrote (in case you need more details)